# Match ROI or shape in several images for analysis

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I have a lot of images to use. But this question I am going to just use the first and last image.

Image 1 of 83

[image: image description]

Image 83 of 83

[image: image description]

I ran Image 1 through this code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def process(filename, key):
   gwash = cv2.imread(filename)
   gwashBW = cv2.cvtColor(gwash, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gwashBW,179,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
   kernel = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
   erosion = cv2.erode(thresh1, kernel,iterations = 1) 
   opening = cv2.morphologyEx(erosion, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
   closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel) 
   _, contours ,_ = cv2.findContours(closing,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

   areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
   idx = np.argmax(areas)
   cnt = contours[idx]

   mask = np.zeros_like(gwash)
   cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, idx, (255,255,255), -1) 
   out = np.zeros_like(gwash) 
   out[mask == 255] = gwash[mask == 255]

   cv2.imwrite('img/out{}.jpg'.format(key),out)
   print idx
```

[image: image description]

This one result I have gotten better and worst results.

Here is the contour code I used and result

```
import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import imutils
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    def process(filename, key):
        image = cv2.imread(filename)

        resized = imutils.resize(image, width=600)
        ratio = image.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(resized, (5, 5), 0)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        lab = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        imagem = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)
        th4 = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
        gray_2 = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        gray_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (15, 15), 0)
        thresh_2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 1)
        kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
        closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=500)
        cnts = cv2.findContours(closing.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts2 = cv2.findContours(closing.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


        cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
        cnts2 = cnts2[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts2[1]

            # loop over the contours
        for c in cnts:
              # compute the center of the contour
              M = cv2.moments(c)
              if M["m00"] != 0:
                  cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
                  cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

              else:
                  cX, cY = 0, 0

              # multiply the contour (x, y)-coordinates by the resize ratio,
              # then draw the contours and the name of the shape and labeled
              # color on the image
              c = c.astype("float")
              c *= ratio
              c = c.astype("int")
              cX *= ratio
              cY *= ratio
              cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 5)
              cv2.circle(image, (int(cX),int(cY)),5,300,3)  

        #r = 100.0 / image.shape[1]
        #dim = (100, int(image.shape[0] *r))

        #imageresized = cv2.resize(image,(2048,2048),dim,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imwrite( 'i/image_{}.jpg'.format(key) ,QR_final )
        print 'image_{}.jpg'.format(key)
```

[image: image description]

So my question is what would the best approach be to accurately find the canvas shape in all the photos using python ?

Comment: That depends a lot on what the other 81 images look like...

Comment: @barny word that makes sense then what about the 2 presented ? thanks !

Comment: So what you're saying is that you haven't solved #83. Yes, looks difficult, but there is a whitish border around the picture. Use that?

Comment: No I haven't. I am thinking about using FLANN. Could you be more specific about the whitish border the table ? thanks !

Comment: Go for it. I mean the whitish border around the picture.

Comment: There are only 82 pictures. It wouldn't take too long to pick all the pictures out manually, in fact much easier than trying to automate it and then still having to manually pick out the ones the automation can't handle.

Comment: When you say manually , do you mean photoshop ? or with opencv ?

Comment: By hand, marking the extents, doing it yourself, the Mark I eyeball in action, click-drag-release, copy/paste,...  Yes you coould use photoshop but probably doesn't need to be as expensive/complex a graphics app as that to do a perfectly good job, unless perhaps you need to extensively warp to get rid of perspective. After you've done a few it might be a minute per picture, maybe 1.5 hours and bish bosh, problem solved.